# How to split the div into two column or three column according to result count?

Tags: php

I have been trying to split the column into two column from the foreach results.

Actual code

```
$j=0;
        foreach($data['properties'] as $value){            
            
            if ($j % 2 == 0) {
            $this->html .= '<div class="row">';
            } 
            $this->html .= '<div class="form-group '.$style.'">';
            $this->html .= $this->parse($value);
            $this->html .= '</div>';
            $this->html .= '</div>';
           $j++;
```

Expected output Html code

```
  <div class="row">                                                                                   
      <div class="col-md-6">                                                                                        
   <div class="form-group">                                                                                            
 <label for="firstName1">Number :</label>                                                                                            
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName1"> </div>                                                                                    
</div>                                                                                    
  <div class="col-md-6">                                                                                        
    <div class="form-group">                                                                                            
     <label for="lastName1">Date of Birth :</label>                                                                                            
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName1"> </div>                                                                                    
   </div>                                                                                
     </div>
```

Comment: I think the second: ```$this->html .= '</div>';``` should just be called when `($j % 2 == 0)`

Comment: Hi, please make a formatting effort when sharing a snippet of code.